# Constant distance ratio from all points of a circumference to a point inside and outside of it

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

given a circle of radius $r$, centered at the origin, and a point  $P_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ inside the circle ($x_1^2 + y_1^2 < r^2$), find a point $P_2 = (x_2,y_2)$ outside of it ($x_2^2 + y_2^2 > r^2$) such that, the ratio of the distances from any point $P = (x,y)$ of the circumference (x^2 + y^2 = r^2) is constant:
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{d(P,P_1)}{d(P,P_2)} = k, \;\;\;\; k \in \mathbb{R}^+
\end{equation*}
what i want to know is if $P_2$ exists, if its unique and if a formula can be found to determine it from the coordinates of $P_1$ and the value of $r$.

regarding the motivation for this problem, i was thinking about this  as it relates to poles and zeros of Z transfer functions in all pass filters, i know  and have confirmed that in the case of the unit circle, with $P_1 = re^{i\theta}$ (0 < r < 1) then choosing $P_2 = \frac{1}{P_1^*} = \frac{1}{r}e^{i\theta}$ satisfies the condition and k = r. with that i have the existence and formula part of my question answered but i wish to know if there is more than one possible choice of $P_2$ and also how to come up with the solution in the first place.

Comment: Let the diameter through $P_1$ intersect the circle at $A,B$, then choose $P_2$ to be the [harmonic conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate) of $P_1$ with respect to $A,B$, in other words $P_2$ is the point that divides $AB$ externally in the same ratio that $P_1$ divides it internally. Then the ratio of distances to $P_1,P_2$ is constant for all points on the circle. This is in fact the defining property of [Apollonian circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius).